# Vuejs computed and watch

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I was reading this Vue guide about [computed and watcher properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html%5B%5D%5B1%5D%20%20%20%20%20%5B1%5D:%20https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html).

I was wondering about this part: `this.debouncedGetAnswer = _.debounce(this.getAnswer, 500)` in the **created** property.

My question is

1. is this formula going to add `this.debouncedGetAnswer` in the `data` or `methods` option/property of the component? Because I can see that `debouncedGetAnswer` is accessed with this like you would have if it is inside the `data` or `methods` property of the component. Any `this.propertyName` would be added to the vue component?
2. Also in the watch `question`, how do I know that functions can have argument like that? I tried console log of `newQuestion` and `oldQuestion` and saw the old and new value of the input. I am a beginner and I've been seeing a lot of functions that have arguments that I do not know they come from, but it is like they are inherent or something.

Thank you!

```html
<div id="watch-example">
  <p>
    Ask a yes/no question:
    <input v-model="question">
  </p>
  <p>{{ answer }}</p>
</div>


<!-- Since there is already a rich ecosystem of ajax libraries    -->
<!-- and collections of general-purpose utility methods, Vue core -->
<!-- is able to remain small by not reinventing them. This also   -->
<!-- gives you the freedom to use what you're familiar with.      -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios@0.12.0/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script>
var watchExampleVM = new Vue({
  el: '#watch-example',
  data: {
    question: '',
    answer: 'I cannot give you an answer until you ask a question!'
  },
  watch: {
    // whenever question changes, this function will run
    question: function (newQuestion, oldQuestion) {
      this.answer = 'Waiting for you to stop typing...'
      this.debouncedGetAnswer()
    }
  },
  created: function () {
    // _.debounce is a function provided by lodash to limit how
    // often a particularly expensive operation can be run.
    // In this case, we want to limit how often we access
    // yesno.wtf/api, waiting until the user has completely
    // finished typing before making the ajax request. To learn
    // more about the _.debounce function (and its cousin
    // _.throttle), visit: https://lodash.com/docs#debounce
    this.debouncedGetAnswer = _.debounce(this.getAnswer, 500)
  },
  methods: {
    getAnswer: function () {
      if (this.question.indexOf('?') === -1) {
        this.answer = 'Questions usually contain a question mark. ;-)'
        return
      }
      this.answer = 'Thinking...'
      var vm = this
      axios.get('https://yesno.wtf/api')
        .then(function (response) {
          vm.answer = _.capitalize(response.data.answer)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          vm.answer = 'Error! Could not reach the API. ' + error
        })
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`debouncedGetAnswer` won't be added to `data` or `methods` because you didn't add it there. It doesn't serve a good purpose to add it to `methods` because debouncing is generally should be applied to component instance, not all instances. It's possible to add it to `data` by adding it to `data` instead of `created` but this isn't needed because `debouncedGetAnswer` won't benefit from being reactive.

`watch` functions are callbacks. `newQuestion` and `oldQuestion` parameters are provided by Vue. This is specified in [API documentation](http://how%20do%20I%20know%20that%20functions%20can%20have%20argument%20like%20that).

Comment: But why there is such line `this.debouncedGetAnswer = _.debounce(this.getAnswer, 500)`? `this` refers to the component right? When you do `this.someName`, that means `someName` is part of the component. Why was `this.debouncedGetAnswer` like this? Then `this.debouncedGetAnswer`  is accessed in the `created` part like it is like a data or method.

Comment: Component instance is composed of `data`, `methods`, `computed` and any other properties you assign explicitly to `this`. ` this.debouncedGetAnswer` is a part of the component since the moment it was assigned in `created`. It doesn't have the magic that is done with `data`, etc properties but here the method doesn't need it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to limit HTTP calls by debounce function, you can try to do these ways:

1. Use `:value` and `@input` to instead of `v-model`

```
<input :value="question" @input="debouncedGetAnswer($event)" />
```

2. implement `debouncedGetAnswer` on the methods of component

```
 methods: {
    debouncedGetAnswer: _.debounce(function (event) {
      const inputValue = event.target.value;
      this.getAnswer(inputValue);
    }, 500),
    getAnswer: function (newQuestionValue) {
      // call API
    }
```

**full example**

https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-germain-25kcd

```js
<template>
  <div id="watch-example">
    <p>
      Ask a yes/no question:
      <input :value="question" @input="debouncedGetAnswer($event)" />
    </p>
    <p>{{ answer }}</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import _ from "lodash";
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data: function () {
    return {
      question: "",
      answer: "I cannot give you an answer until you ask a question!",
    };
  },
  methods: {
    debouncedGetAnswer: _.debounce(function (event) {
      const inputValue = event.target.value;
      this.getAnswer(inputValue);
    }, 500),
    getAnswer: function (newQuestionValue) {
      if (newQuestionValue.indexOf("?") === -1) {
        this.answer = "Questions usually contain a question mark. ;-)";
        return;
      }
      this.answer = "Thinking...";
      var vm = this;
      axios
        .get("https://yesno.wtf/api")
        .then(function (response) {
          vm.answer = _.capitalize(response.data.answer);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          vm.answer = "Error! Could not reach the API. " + error;
        });
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
</style>
```